# Use interpolation in the route-href attribute

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to create a dynamic menu by looping over all routes of the router.

Simplified class (TypeScript flavour):

```js
@inject(Router)
export class NavBar {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}
}
```

Simplified view:

```html
<div repeat.for="route in router.routes">
    <a route-href="route: ${route.name}">${route.title}</a>
</div>
```

Although it works if I simply print out the properties of the routes in the loop, the approach doesn't seem to be working for the `route-href` attribute. Any ideas how I can make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

`route-href="route: ${route.name}"`

to this:

`route-href="route.bind: route.config.name"`

Interpolation binding only works on single-value attributes, not on custom attributes with bindable properties.

And just in case you were not aware: the `router.routes` property  is a list of type [NavModel](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/router/1.0.5/class/NavModel), which has a property `config` which contains the `RouteConfig`.

Answer (score 2):

In the nav bar you do not need to use route-href, you could do:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li repeat.for="route of router.navigation" class="${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.in" href.bind="route.href">${route.title}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

A route-href can be used however if you want the user to click on a specific link that requires a parameter.

```
<tr repeat.for="log of logs">
    <td><a route-href="route: log-details; params.bind: { logId: log.id }">${log.id}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference between `href.bind` and `route-href`.